# A planet with different and shared atmospheres, creating very different surface exteriors/appearances

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction

For a story I'm working on I have this fantasy world, which for the most part looks like Earth in the sense of trees, fields, mountains etc. There might be some unusual or nonexisting formations in there, but they can be there because of magic in the world or other reasons which aren't that important.

I also thought of a world (or environment) which has a very different atmosphere, and which could look like something out of the game No Man's Sky (e.g. brightly colored earth, rocks and vegetation, and strange creatures inhabiting it). I didn't really think about the different compound of that atmosphere, i.e. which gases and other elements it would me made up of, but perhaps some of you could help me with that.

I was wondering if a planet, possibly influenced by a form of magic which can influence and mutate nature, could have two different atmospheres, which would result in the earth having very different appearances. In a crude example: a planet which is 70% earthlike in surface appearance, and 30% alienlike, similiar to things seen in No Man's Sky. Is this in any way possible, and would the transition be quite direct or very gradual?

Comment: With magic anything is possible - that's what magic is all about!

Comment: @Mołot I thought that too, such a simple solution

Comment: @Mendeleev That's why i dislike statements like "influenced by a form of magic" - either there are rules for magic in the question, or the answer will always be "magic, d'oh" :(

Answer (score 3):

One way to make this work would be if the 'magic' was that old science-fiction standby the force-field. It is also necessary some highly advanced hypertechnological aliens visited the planet established a series of force-fields to sequester thirty percent of the otherwise Earthlike planet's surface. The force-fields will be primarily designed to keep what will become two different atmospheres separate and distinctly apart.

Once the force-fields were up and working they xenoformed the 30% of the planet. Giving it a different atmosphere from the rest of the planet. Then seeded it with alien lifeforms that can live, thrive and survive in the xenoformed environment. This environment will be large and extensive enough to self-sustaining. It will have a diversity of biomes and a range of ecologies.

The force-fields will be permeable to solid objects, like animals. This will allow organisms to pass between environments. if the atmospheres of two environments are too different, then organisms will perish if they stay too long. However, over enough time evolution might allow adaptation and organisms will arise that can survive in both environments. This is not guaranteed, but it is potentially possible.

Xenoformed and xenoforming is the alien equivalent of terraforming planets to make them suitable for alien biospheres, by aliens for aliens.

Answer (score 3):

An easy and non-magical way to get something like that is to make effect depend on rather heavy gasses normally stratifying quite low in some (large) depression.

Weather should be with little wind to avoid dispersion, but enough movement to avoid complete stratification (it would push oxygen away, which would have some impact on fauna).

Gas may be organic (psychedelic?) and produced by special flora which, in turn evolved to need its presence; this would keep it (and associated flora) contained in places where atmospheric conditions avoid dispersion.

Variations on the concept are possible depending on your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

**You probably don't want an answer like if its magic its up to you so**

On Earth we have places with different climates already, ranges in temperature being very extreme with the different deserts on either end of the spectrum, although maybe not as extreme as your ideas they are clear, and although I'm no expert I do believe it might be possible.

Comment: If I'm wrong, **MAGIC**